# How do I make this pygame program to change from a drawing state to non drawing state when clicked and vice versa?

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent, paint, mouseclick-event

I want this simulation of paint to work such that if the mouse button is pressed, it starts drawing ( button is released instantly).  Again, when the button is pressed, it should stop drawing.

There is no error. In the present case shared it basically always remains the pen down (drawing) mode. I have tried the `get_pressed` function but succeeded in drawing only when the key remains pressed. I tried making it equal to `(a,0,0)` and vary `a` to achieve the goal but was unsuccessful.

After a few attempts it resulted in the drawing mode turning on or off instantaneously instead of on click.

Here's the part that controls the action:

```
while keepGoing:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keepGoing = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            lineEnd = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                pygame.draw.line(background, drawColor, lineStart, lineEnd, lineWidth)
            lineStart = lineEnd
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            myData = (event, background, drawColor, lineWidth, keepGoing)
            myData = checkKeys(myData)
            (event, background, drawColor, lineWidth, keepGoing) = myData
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    myLabel = showStats(drawColor, lineWidth)
    screen.blit(myLabel, (450, 450))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Complete Code link:  http://codeshare.io/gbPc0

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is this better? I think I followed all the other guidelines. @That1Guy

Comment: That's better but you're still not asking a clear question. You simply state your goal and share some code with us. What exactly is the problem? What have you tried so far? What is the expected result? How does your current result differ from what you expect? Are you receiving an error? If so, what it is it, and what is the entire traceback?

Comment: No, there is no error. In the present case shared it basically always remains the pen down ( drawing) mode.  I have tried the get_pressed function but succeeded on drawing only when the key remains pressed.  I tried making it equal to (a,0,0) and vary a to achieve the goal but was unsuccessful.  After a few attempts it resulted in the drawing mode turning on or off instantaneously instead of on click.

Comment: That is all good information. Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: Much better. I edited your question to clean it up a bit. I've also removed my downvote.

Comment: You need to keep track of your two states.  Normal and DrawMode.  Each time they click, you toggle the mode.  While in DrawMode you capture mouse movement and add it to the drawing. When they click again finish your line and toggle back to normal mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of what you want to do:

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
line_start = None

while True:
  mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
      break
    if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
      line_start = None if line_start else mouse_pos
  else:
    if line_start:
      pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.color.Color('White'), line_start, mouse_pos, 1)
      line_start = mouse_pos
    pygame.display.flip()
    continue
  break
```

It keeps track of the state (*are we in drawing or non-drawing mode?*) by simply storing `None` or the last mouse position in `line_start` on a `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It solves the problem. Now I can modify it as I want.